# Could not retrieve data as JSON object

Tags: php, mysql, json, pdo

I have a mysql table stored in MAMP PhpMyAdmin called 'employees'. The structure is

- Employees(id,name location)

  I have a php code that retrieve data as JSON object and display on browser. But When I run it all the values are 'null'

Here is my script:

```
<?php
// Enter username and password
$username = root;
$password = root;

// Create database connection using PHP Data Object (PDO)
$db = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=movies", $username, $password);

// Identify name of table within database
$table = 'employees';

// Create the query - here we grab everything from the table
$stmt = $db->query('SELECT * from '.$table);

// Close connection to database
$db = NULL;

$result = array();

while($rows = $stmt->fetch()){
    array_push($result, array('name' => $row[0],
                              'location'  => $row[1]));
};

echo json_encode(array('result' => $result));

?>
```

Comment: Inside the while loop, it should be rows[0], not row[0] as per the variables you have used

Comment: You're missing quotes in `$username` and `$password`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are using wrong PDO function. To get plural row*s* you need to use [PDO::fetchAll()](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo#fetchall), not fetch():

```
$rows = $db->query('SELECT name,location from employees')->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
echo json_encode($rows);
```

is all the code you need.

Answer (score 0):

You're using a wrong variable name inside your while loop, see:

`while($rows = $stmt->fetch())`

And ... inside your loop:

`array_push($result, array('name' => $row[0],
                              'location'  => $row[1]));`

Try changing `$rows = $stmt->fetch()` to `$row = $stmt->fetch()`.

Answer (score -1):

Before your try to echo json_encoded string, you need to check if any results are being returned from database at all. Try to do

```
echo "<pre>";
print_r($result);
echo "</pre>";
```

It is likely that you are getting nothing in `$result` variable. But considering that it is not empty, json could be `null` data you are trying to encode it is not `UTF-8` encoded.